# cant get session to save number PHP

Tags: php, session, random

im fairly new to PHP but I am trying to make a guessing game.
the idea is you guess the number between 1-100 and the code is meant to have a randomly assigned code to guess until guessed, currently just working on the assigning the number. so it doesnt randomize everytime I attempt to guess.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[var_answer] = rand (1, 100);
$var_number = $_REQUEST['number'];
if($var_number == $_SESSION[var_answer]){
    echo " That is correct ;)";
}
else if($var_number <0 || $var_number>100){
    echo " Sorry your guess has to be between 0 and 100";
}else if($var_number==" "||$var_number==""){
    echo " Please take a guess first!";
}else if($var_number < $_SESSION[var_answer]){
    echo " Smaller than mine";
}else if($var_number > $_SESSION[var_answer]){
    echo " Larger than mine";
}
echo '<br/><a href="RNGG.php"> return</a>';
?>
```

so far the number is randomizing but as I said isnt saving per session.

Comment: Your codes work for me success

Comment: echo `$_SESSION[var_answer]` and see what you get

Comment: The answer gets overwritten with each request.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You don't need to store anything in session with the current algorithm - you are generating random number all the time.

Comment: By your logic, the user needs to guess _before_ which number will be randomized later

Comment: I suggest you to add a start for a game to start.

Comment: Also, if you want numbers between 0-100, `rand(0,100)` is not what you want, you need to use `echo rand()&100;`

Comment: What actually happened in this code is, everytime you input a number session is being set. So, try to cover this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
$_SESSION[var_answer] = rand (1, 100);
$var_number = $_REQUEST['number'];
if($var_number == $_SESSION[var_answer]){
    echo " That is correct ;)";
}
```

You are overwriting the session variable every time the page is reloaded. As far as I understand, you want to store the number in session, until the person guesses it. Try this:

```
//put a random number into session, if the variable is not defined
if(!isset($_SESSION['var_answer']))
{
    $_SESSION['var_answer'] = rand (1, 100);
}

$var_number = $_REQUEST['number'];
if($var_number == $_SESSION['var_answer']){
    echo " That is correct ;)";
    //undefine the variable if it's guessed
    unset($_SESSION['var_answer']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I dont know why i didnt consider the overwriting factor thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION[var_answer]` must be changed to `$_SESSION['var_answer']` everywhere and it will solve your problem.
So your code must be

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var_answer'] = rand (1, 100);
$var_number = $_REQUEST['number'];
if($var_number == $_SESSION['var_answer']){
    echo " That is correct ;)";
}
else if($var_number <0 || $var_number>100){
    echo " Sorry your guess has to be between 0 and 100";
}else if($var_number==" "||$var_number==""){
    echo " Please take a guess first!";
}else if($var_number < $_SESSION['var_answer']){
    echo " Smaller than mine";
}else if($var_number > $_SESSION['var_answer']){
    echo " Larger than mine";
}
echo '<br/><a href="RNGG.php"> return</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Not required, yes, it is a bad practice but that's not the reason

Comment: No, even without quotes it will work, just generating a notice: "PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant var_answer"